# powershell to delete items from a list where created date < "1/1/2011"

Tags: powershell

Is there a quick powershell script to delete items from a list where created date is less than some date? Also, would the deleted items be in the recycle bin (in the event business team wants to restore some items).

Comment: Nice job finding the solution! Can you post it as an answer now?

Answer (score 5):

On behalf of author, the answer was found here:
http://blogs.flexnetconsult.co.uk/colinbyrne/2008/02/26/PowerShellSharePointThreeWaysToDeleteAListItemIDCAMLStringMatching.aspx

```
[void][System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sitecollectionURL") 
$web = $site.rootweb 
$list = $web.Lists["Name of the List"]

$caml='<Where>
        <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2011-12-31T02:32:20Z</Value>
        </Leq>
    </Where>'

$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$query.Query=$caml | Write-Output

$items=$list.GetItems($query) 
$listItemsTotal = $items.Count;

for($x=$listItemsTotal-1;$x -ge 0; $x--)
{
        $items[$x].Delete()
}

$web.Dispose() 
$site.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for better performance and (no recycle bin), if you want a bulk delete, this will be much faster. Comparing the above code with this one, this code shows that deleting basic 600 items from a list took 14 seconds; whilst it took 6 minutes and 16 seconds when using the bad coded script.

REFERENCE https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ahmedamin/2017/08/03/bulk-delete-sharepoint-items-in-a-large-list-using-powershell/

```
$web = get-spweb "URL Here"
$list = $web.lists["LIST NAME"]
$caml='<Where>
        <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2018-5-31T02:32:20Z</Value>
        </Leq>
    </Where>'
$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$query.Query=$caml | Write-Output
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$query.RowLimit = 1000
$query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>"
$query.ViewFieldsOnly = $true
do
{
   $listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
   $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
   foreach($item in $listItems)
   {
     Write-Host "Deleting Item - $($item.Id)"
     $list.GetItemById($item.Id).delete()
   }
}
while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can delete all files or documents from the given created dates(**From Date and To Date**) - from all document library in a site using the below PowerShell script:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
cls



$fileName = "File_Deleting_Report"
#'yyyyMMddhhmm   yyyyMMdd
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
#$filename =  $enddate + '_VMReport.doc'  
$logFileName = $fileName +"_"+ $enddate+"_Log.txt"   
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value  
$directoryPath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path  

$directoryPathForLog=$directoryPath+"\"+"LogFiles"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForLog))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForLog
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   


#$logPath = $directoryPath + "\" + $logFileName 

$logPath = $directoryPathForLog + "\" + $logFileName 

$isLogFileCreated = $False 



#DLL location

$directoryPathForDLL=$directoryPath+"\"+"Dependency Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForDLL))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForDLL

        } 

#DLL location

$clientDLL=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
$clientDLLRuntime=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path $clientDLL
Add-Type -Path $clientDLLRuntime


#File Download location

$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation=$directoryPath+"\"+"Downloaded Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        } 

#File Download location



function Write-Log([string]$logMsg)  
{   
    if(!$isLogFileCreated){   
        Write-Host "Creating Log File..."   
        if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPath))  
        {  
            Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   
        else   
        {   
            $script:isLogFileCreated = $True   
            Write-Host "Log File ($logFileName) Created..."   
            [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
            Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
        }   
    }   
    else   
    {   
        [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
    }   
} 




#Parameters
$siteURL="https://globalsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/SharePointRND/"
$listName="Documents"
$fromDate="2019-12-08"
$toDate="2019-12-12"
$downloadLocation=$directoryPathForFileDownloadLocation;
$userName = "Global-sharepoint@globalsharepoint.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "YourSPOPassWord"
$securePassword= $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$batchSize =1000

#Parameters ends here.


#Setup the Context
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $securePassword)

  <#
  $web = $ctx.Web
  $ctx.Load($web)
  $ctx.Load($web.Webs)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()#>



  #The below code is for root site

$docLibraryColl=$ctx.Web.Lists
$ctx.Load($docLibraryColl)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($oneList in $docLibraryColl)
{

if($oneList.BaseTemplate -eq "101" -and $oneList.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $oneList.Hidden -eq $False -and $oneList.IsCatalog -eq $False -and $oneList.IsApplicationList -eq $False) 
{



#Get the List
$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($oneList.Title)
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$emptyString = ""
#Define CAML Query to get Files from the list in batches
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery


$startDateVar=$fromDate+"T13:35:58Z"
#$startDate=Get-Date -Date $startDateVar; 
$endDateVar=$toDate+"T13:36:34Z"
#$endDate=Get-Date -Date $endDateVar;



$Query.ViewXml = "@
    <View Scope='Recursive'>
        <Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$startDateVar</Value>
         </Geq>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$endDateVar</Value>
         </Leq>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>        
    </View>"



$count =0

#Get List Items in Batches
Do
{


    $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
    $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $ListItems.Count

    #Update Postion of the ListItemCollectionPosition
    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition

    If ($ListItems.Count -eq 0) { Break }

    $fileCount=1;

    #Update List Item
    ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
    {                    


            try
            {

              $Ctx.Load($Item.File)
              $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

              $Item.File.DeleteObject();
              $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()              


             Write-Host $Item.File.Name "has been deleted successfully" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen




        }
        catch
        {
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +$file.Name
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
            Write-Log $ErrorMessage 

        }       



    }
    Write-Host "============================================================="
    Write-Host $count
    Write-Host "============================================================="

}While ($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

}


}
```

**Script execution example:**

[image]

**Note:**

- In your scenario just need to change the **from date** and **To date** accordingly.

For detailed steps please refer the below article:

[Delete All Files from document library for the given date – PowerShell CSOM](https://global-sharepoint.com/powershell/sharepoint-online-delete-all-files-from-sharepoint-online-site-from-a-given-date/)