# Powershell to delete all items from a list based on created date

Tags: 2010, powershell

I have this powershell script to delete all items from a list:

```
$siteURL = "URL"
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite ( $siteURL )
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$oList = $web.Lists["ListName"];
$collListItems = $oList.Items;
$count = $collListItems.Count -1;
for($intIndex = $count; $intIndex -ge 0; $intIndex--)
{
   $collListItems[$intIndex].Delete();
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to edit this script to only delete items that were created over 90 days ago (or delete items that were created before a certain date)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a question which is similar to yours and already answered:

You can replace the Date beeing compared with this:

```
$DateToCompare = (Get-date).AddDays(-90)
```

[powershell to delete items from a list where created date < "1/1/2011"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/powershell-to-delete-items-from-a-list-where-created-date-1-1-2011)