# Items stuck Checked Out, can't check in

Tags: 2010, document-library, check-out, delete

I'm doing a purge of a bunch of list/libraries used in a QA environment (using the script [found here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16024/powershell-to-delete-items-from-a-list-where-created-date-1-1-2011)) and have run into a snag where 3 items in a particular library are checked out to a user but I am unable to check them in, discard the check out or delete them any other way.

The items are from a restored backup from our production environment so I have a feeling that may be part of the issue. When I try to check them in I get a file not found SharePoint error. When the script tried to delete the items it shows a "this item is checked out" message.

I haven't able to delete the 3 items by any method using the web page nor any scripts I've tried. Short of getting into the content DB directly which I do not want to do, I can't think of any other way to force a check in and delete the items.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you taken ownership of the checked out files?

Comment: They already have a checked in version so they don't show up under the 'Manage files which have no checked in version' page. I also tried deleting them from the Explorer window but still no luck.

Comment: Can't delete, undo check-out or check-in from Designer either. It just complains that the file is checked out already.

Comment: Does it state who it is checked out to, a user, the system, admin, etc.?

Comment: In the browser it shows the actual user (two users who were part of the UAT), but in designer it shows "file is checked out to ." so I have a feeling that even if I get the user to try and check it in/delete it they will receive a file not found error as well.